# Why does one Firebase Auth login burn through 21 DB read operations?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Once the daily time period reset today, I tested some auth operations, in which I don't at all use Firebase.Firestore. All I did was login, and then logout. something to note, is that once authenticated, there are not yet ANY listeners or any other Firestore operations. the only firestore operations exist in the registration flow.

here is the login action:

```
export const loginUser = (email, password) => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: types.LOGIN_USER });
        // listen for change in auth state before signing in
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            firebase
                .auth()
                .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .then((userCredential) => {
                    console.log('User Credential: ' + JSON.stringify(userCredential));
                    const unsubscribe = firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
                        if (user) {
                            console.log('Logged in: ' + user.email);
                            loginUserSuccess(dispatch, user);
                            resolve(user);
                        } else {
                            console.log('Authentication state changed, user object is null...');
                        }
                    });
                    // No longer need to listen to auth state
                    unsubscribe();
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log('Error during Email sign-in: ' + error);
                    loginUserFail(dispatch, error.message);
                });
        });
    };
};
```

(loginUserSuccess/Fail only dispatch to reducer nothing else)

on logout this action runs:

```
export const logoutUser = () => {
    return (dispatch) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            firebase
                .auth()
                .signOut()
                .then(() => {
                    dispatch({ type: types.RESET_AUTH });
                    console.log('Dispatching types.RESET_AUTH');
                    resolve();
                })
                .catch((error) => reject(error.message));
        });
    };
};
```

Firestore usage before this test were all at 0. usage data after this one cycle of logging in/logging out:

```
reads: 21
writes: 0
deletes: 0
peak connections: 0
```

What's going on here... why did this cost 21 reads? if you need more info, ask. the only thing I noticed, is the userCredential that I log has exactly 22 total object properties (not 21, but suspiciously close). but if a promised user credential is whats causing all these DB reads...that makes zero sense

EDIT: without doing any other tests && refreshing the firestore usage page, it changed to 22 reads!

Comment: Firebase Authentication calls do not use Firestore in any way. The Firestore read operations can't be coming from there. Did you open the Firestore console by any chance? Because that will read data, since it needs to display that data. If you still have questions about these operations, and they can't be explained from the code you shared, [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: thanks frank. im reading the usage data from console.firebase, yes...but initially when I wen to the console, before the test..the data was all at 0 for the day. then running the login/logout test it went up. but the second time I tried with the same test user account, the reads did not go up. then I tried with a second test account, the reads went up the same 22 readdressing-amount

Comment: The Firebase console is the #1 source of unexpected reads. The code you've shown here won't be responsible for any reads, as Frank said.

Comment: that is extremely confusing. if thats the case the console is the reason for almost 1000 reads in under a week...that cant be...